# How to change Video PlayBack Quality with AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem, videoquality

How can I change Video Quality like YouTube?

Currently, I am playing with original quality and I am giving options like 360p, 480p, 720p for changing quality.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 7):

You cant do that simply with `AVplayer`. you require diffrent URL for different quality video. When user select other quality, you can switch to that video with  [replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1390806-replacecurrentitemwithplayeritem)  method fo AVPlayer.

```
AVPlayerItem *playeriem= [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:urlOfSelectedQualityVideo];
[playeriem seekToTime:player.currentTime];
[player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playeriem];
```

Comment: i have only one Video URL.

Comment: @Kuldeep In that case, You cant switch between quality.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do such things like converting video you should use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) library.
Try to look for some libraries that use ffmpeg on github.

Like this one: https://github.com/iMoreApps/ffmpeg-avplayer-for-ios-tvos

You can't do that with AVPlayer. When just streaming you use M3U index files, TS files containing the video data and just switch streams.

Check out Apple's [HLS Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html) and playlist [Examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2288/_index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can also create multiple renditions of m3u8 one with lower quality video bitrates say 128k to 650k and another one with 650k + to higher bitrates and use a higher quality stream URL suggested in the answer above

```
AVPlayerItem *playeriem= [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:urlOfSelectedQualityVideo];
```